# Using に対して vs に応えて

Tags: grammar

I was doing some practice JLPT questions, and am having trouble determining when to best use に対して vs に応えて.

所長は今回の事件（　）どう責任をとるつもりなのか。

The correct answer is listed as に対して.

I choose に応えて thinking that 'in response to this incident' made sense.  However, thinking about it more, I suppose that に応えて prefers to take an action verb...  Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

応える has much narrower meaning than English "respond". It is almost only used in the context of human communication, and means "give what they expect/deserve in return for their (incoming) action" (hint: it has the same reading as 答える "answer").

> 通信に応える *respond to the transmission*
> 疑念に応える *address the suspicion*
> 要望に応える *respect/fulfill the request*
> 期待に応える *live up to the expectation (directed at you)*

事件 is just a fact, not a message from anybody, so you can confront it, but cannot 応える.

Comment: I agree in general, but something like 期待 isn't really a message either. It seems to me that 応える is about responding to something that results from human thought/feeling/intent, whereas 対する can also be used when responding to something purely situational.

Comment: @Will I actually want to say something like "communicative activity coming to you". Do you come up with any good wording?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. On second thought, maybe it's useful to note that it seems like all the applicable 応える examples involve some kind of "_expectation directed at_ (or _centered on_) _you_".

Comment: @Will Ah, I think now I know what that English phrase really means. Thank you.